# R - Creating dummy to evaluate days of the week effect

Tags: r, time-series, regression, linear-regression

I was trying to create week day dummies, and the start date is a Sunday, and number of total observation period is 271. And I used these code:

```
mon <- rep(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0), T/7) 
tue <- rep(c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0), T/7)
wed <- rep(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0), T/7)
thu <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0), T/7)
fri <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0), T/7)
sat <- rep(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1), T/7)
sun <- rep(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0), T/7) 

linreg4 <- lm(formula = hits ~ 0 + mon + tue + wed + thu + fri + sat + + sun) 

summary(linreg4)
```

and got error saying:

**"Error in model.frame.default(formula = hits ~ 0 + mon + tue + wed + thu +  :
variable lengths differ (found for 'mon')"**

Please help me to fixed this error, as I rearranged the sequence order, the error still presents.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe just a typo `sat + + sun`?

Comment: What is `T`? It's not good to assign a variable to `T` as by default it equals `TRUE` and when I look at these variables eg `wed` it gives me `numeric(0)` as the output

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because 271 /7 is not an integer, so when you use `rep` it actually rounds down:

```
total = 271
hits = rnorm(271,10,1)

mon <- rep(c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0), total/7) 

length(mon)
[1] 266

lm(hits ~ mon)

Error in model.frame.default(formula = hits ~ mon, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'mon')
```

You can essentially repeat a vector of the days starting with Sunday, and take only the first 271:

```
days = rep(c("sun","mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat"),ceiling(total/7))
days = days[1:total]

linreg4 <- lm(formula = hits ~ 0 + days)
```